# Updating child recyclerView item from parent recyclerView button click

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a parent recyclerView and each item of parent has a child recyclerView. I have a toggle button on my parent recyclerView, when that button is selected I have to update the child recyclerView list.
I tried every possible way to update the child list but didn't succeed. Below is my code of parent adapter from where I am tryig to update the list:

```
 holder.toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        videosArrayList.clear();
                        allVideoExceptPersonalizedList.clear();
                        allVideoArrayList.clear();
                      setDataForCategory(1,holder,position);
                        holder.mAdapter.UpdateList(videosArrayList);

                    } else {
                        videosArrayList.clear();
                        allVideoExceptPersonalizedList.clear();
                        allVideoArrayList.clear();
                        setDataForCategory(2,holder,position);
                        holder.mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        holder.mAllVideoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            });
```

In the above code videoArrayList is my child list items and setDataForCategory is giving me an updated list.

I also tried to bind the adapter again but that makes my childRecyclerView empty that it is clearing the list but not adding the new data.

```
 holder.mAdapter = new TutorialVideoAdapter(mctx, mFrg, mTracker, videosArrayList,
                                parentView, parent_fragment, catList.get(position),parentCategoryId,
                                holder.recyclerView_tutorial_personalized, new ITutorialImageClick() {
                            @Override
                            public void imageOnClick(View v, int position) {
                                int newTutorialCount = tutorialViewModel.getNewTutorialCount(categoryName, myParams,priority);

                                holder.img_category.setBadgeValue(newTutorialCount);
                            }
                        });
                        holder.recyclerView_tutorial_personalized.setAdapter(holder.mAdapter);
                        holder.recyclerView_tutorial_personalized.invalidate();
```

Below is my code for child adapter where I am actually updating the list:

```
public void UpdateList(List<VideoDetailModel> videosArrayList){
        mVideoList.clear();
        mVideoList.addAll(videosArrayList);
        notifyDataSetChanged(); 
}
```

I also tried resetting my adapter and calling childRecyclerView.invalidate(), but that also didn't help me.

What exactly I am doing wrong?

Comment: After `mVideoList.clear();` your list you need to bind adapter again it's not only working with `notifyDataSetChanged();`. Try to reBind adapter after clear array.

Comment: Let me edit my question again, as I have tried that also but that makes my child recyclerView empty.

Comment: Are you try this `rv.setAdapter(mVideoList);` in update method after clearing arraylist?

Comment: I tried the same but the only the list is getting cleared but the new list is not setting.

Comment: OKay try with a clear list, Assign `adapter = null` and then bind your `adapter`

Comment: I tried that also, but it's not binding the adapter, so my recyclerView is looking empty.